# How to automatically eliminate double-precision math from generated code?

Tags: floating-point, arm, embedded, clang, precision

In our embedded project, targeted for the ARM Cortex M* cores, we are using the ARM clang-based toolchain (v6). We use `float` type for our floating-point math. As we try to minimize footprint, we found out that some space is taken by unnecessary `double`<->`float` conversions.

The source of some of those conversions was the use of literals not including the `f` specifier (e.g., use `12.34` instead of `12.34f`). To eliminate that, I am looking for a compiler option that uses `float` type by default. Looking at the compiler documentation and at the general clang help, I could not find any.

Is there any option (command option, pragma, attribute, etc.) that can achieve that goal?

Comment: Sounds like the solution is to fix the buggy code. You simply shouldn't be mixing double literals with floats and that's no fault of the tool chain. Same goes with function calls, there's always different functions for double and float.

Comment: You can scan your map files for double related calls and trim them that way.  We did this on systems with soft float support (i.e. - no hardware) to prevent the massive CPU hit that floats incurred.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - We already did that and carefully converted the literals to explicit floats. The question asked for an added layer of protection and future proofing.

Comment: You could always create a python script of something to autoscan and flag errors.  Not quite the future proof you want, but at least "now" proof for many nows.

Comment: @Lundin " there's always different functions for double and float." --> Printing a `float` seems to be an exception.

Answer (score 1):

[-fsingle-precision-constant](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is what you are looking for although my personal opinion is that you should avoid it and rather use an explicit cast.

Comment: Thanks. I can't find this option in the armclang documentation, so I assume it is unsupported there.

Comment: In fact, searching gave this post: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-July/088040.html This looks like a GCC option.

Comment: Clang uses -cl-single-precision-constant instead. I currently don't have ARM clang installed, but with clang itself the flag works. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/PhqtfX).

Comment: Looks like armclang does not support this option.